# Unable to find icons in connections tab in SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Connections window is empty. I have tried restarting, reinstalling the sql client, Window>Reset Windows to Factory Settings but still cannot see any connections. Does anyone know what might the issue be

Initially I have added connections and now I am unable to see icons and connections.

Comment: If you have reinstalled the client after reinstalling windows then re-add the connections as well. This is not a programming question and is off-topic for StackOverflow.